# SQL Query optimization in Prestashop solution

Tags: php, sql, optimization, prestashop

I'm working on the layered navigation module with Prestashop solution,
I'm trying to optimize a Sql query which create a tmp table to execute it and by this way create a bottleneck in mysql.

This is the query :

```
SELECT p.*, p.id_category_default, pl.available_later, pl.description_short, pl.link_rewrite, pl.name, i.id_image, il.legend, m.name manufacturer_name, DATEDIFF(p.`date_add`, DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) > 0 AS new 
FROM `ps_category_product` cp 
LEFT JOIN ps_category c ON (c.id_category = cp.id_category) 
LEFT JOIN `ps_product` p ON p.`id_product` = cp.`id_product` 
LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang pl ON (pl.id_product = p.id_product) 
LEFT JOIN ps_image i ON (i.id_product = p.id_product AND i.cover = 1) 
LEFT JOIN ps_image_lang il ON (i.id_image = il.id_image AND il.id_lang = 2) 
LEFT JOIN ps_manufacturer m ON (m.id_manufacturer = p.id_manufacturer) 
WHERE p.`active` = 1 AND c.nleft >= 2 AND c.nright <= 29 AND c.active = 1 AND pl.id_lang = 2 
AND p.id_product IN (74,78,130,146,168,169,178,195,...,297,302,1986,1987,1988,1993,1999,2000,2001) 
GROUP BY p.id_product ORDER BY p.date_upd desc LIMIT 0,48
```

I know the tmp table is created because of the GROUP BY but I don't know how to remove it. If the same process could be done with PHP instead of SQL, it could be a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mybe a bit more info would be nice where and when you need that. Cos if the workload is a problem and you don't find a good solution better to do it as a nightjob.

Comment: Does it run well without the GROUP BY clause? Try removing that clause and explaining to make sure that it wouldn't be using a temporary table anyway.